# How to bring back "Add to home" banner for progressive web app after removed the icon from home screen?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, a2hs

The reason - I made a `Progressive web app`, opened in the browser - all is fine and browser offered me to add it to home screen.

Now, I want to demonstrate this on a presentation, and so - removed the icon from home screen. But for the last whole day I've been playing with the website in chrome a lot, and the banner never appears back.

Is it really a once-in-a-lifetime thing? Or is there something specific I need to do?

Comment: Also, I would like to know how to make a manual link to Add to Homescreen, or at least, shall I just give a message (modal or not) anywhere on my website reminding the user "Hey, add this website to your homescreen for better features!".

Answer (score 18):

The app-install banner prompt is normally presented after you've visited the site at least twice with at least 5 minutes between each visit. Using a Chrome flag, you can bypass these checks so that the banner always appears on every visit:

1. Open Android Chrome.
2. Go to `chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks`
3. Click **Enable**
4. Click **Relaunch Now**

You can also [simulate an *Add To Homescreen* event](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps#add-to-homescreen) from Chrome DevTools:

1. Open Android Chrome on your phone, and navigate to a PWA (e.g., the *Paper Planes* app from https://paperplanes.world).
2. Connect to your Android with a USB cable.
3. From desktop Chrome DevTools, select ***Menu* > *More Tools* > Remote Devices**. *OR* <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> for macOS), and enter "Remote devices".
4. Select your phone by name.
5. Click the **Inspect** button next to the list item corresponding to your PWA (e.g., *Paper Planes*).
6. In the new DevTools pop-up for your PWA, go to the **Application** panel, and click **Add to homescreen**. This should cause the app-install banner to appear in Android Chrome. Note the banner won't appear in the Chrome DevTools screen mirror.

*(steps above verified with Chrome 55 on macOS Sierra, and Android Chrome 57)*

Comment: Enabled the flag, and cleared browsing data, restarted browser but it didn't prompt me again. Does this solution still work?

Comment: Important note: **even** if you enable `chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks`, if you dismiss the install once on a given site, the install prompt will NOT be showed anymore for subsequent visits. The only way to have it displayed again is to delete browser history/cache. (Tested on Chrome Android)

Answer (score 8):

I found another solution - when I go to the settings of chrome mobile and choose `History` -> `Clear browsing data` (make sure that the option to clear `Cookies` is ticked) then click the `Clear Data` button - after that I get again the `app install banner` to add the app to the home screen.

Apparently - it clears not only the data itself, but also makes the browser `forget` everything about this website.

(Strangely - the old icon doesn't go away ... so now I have a few icons on the home screen :D ...)

Comment: This all makes logical sense. And it's up to the user to delete old icons. Do the old icons still function, using your new service worker? That's another question.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, banner refuses to show up again

Comment: In the end I managed to make the banner reappear by explicitly selecting cookies to be cleared, not just site data, so I think that's important to indicate in this answer. This page also contains some useful information regarding some recent changes to the behaviour of the banner: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates

Comment: could you indicate which cookies and site data need to be cleared