# Ask the visitor of the website to add a home desktop shortcut on mobile (progressive-web-app)

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, progressive-web-apps, a2hs

I remember that when I went on certain websites with Chrome Android, there was a bottom popup which displayed something like:

*"Want to install a shortcut on your home desktop? Click here."*

**How to enable this "progressive-web-app" behaviour for Android browsers and iOS browsers, offering to install a desktop shortcut icon?**

---

Here is what I already tried, without success: in the HTML itself:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
<link href="32.png" rel="icon shortcut" sizes="3232" />
<link href="192.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

The `manifest.json` contains:

```
{
  "short_name": "myapp",
  "name": "myapp",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "48.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "72.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    },
   /// etc. same for 96, 144, 192, 512
  ],
  "start_url": "https://example.com",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "description": "Test"
}
```

Note: it's not easy to debug *"Add to home screen"* on a given website, because the prompt doesn't always show if you already visited the website before, see my comment on the accepted answer of [How to bring back "Add to home" banner for progressive web app after removed the icon from home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864121/how-to-bring-back-add-to-home-banner-for-progressive-web-app-after-removed-the)

Comment: Take a look at [Add to Home screen (A2HS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen), it should help you further

Comment: Thank you @Reyno. I created what seems to be a valid manifest (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen#manifest), and I added it in the HTML with `<link rel="manifest" ...>`, but still the popup is not shown, do you know why?

Comment: Well first of all this only works over https (with exception of localhost). Chrome also requires you to have a service worker registered. This is al mention [in the article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen#how_do_you_make_an_app_a2hs-ready). Otherwise I'm not sure what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Did you register a service worker? You can use the below code if you have not done this yet.

```js
navigator?.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
```

You need to create **service-worker.js** file in the folder containing your main JS file

Comment: Thanks. I did it with an empty `sevice-worker.js` but the install banner still doesn't show. Is there a requirement that the service worker does something specific?

Comment: Use the Lighthouse tool in a Chromium-based browser's developer tools

Answer (score 1):

It seems that registering an empty serviceWorker with:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(() => { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); }); }
```

is not enough.

For me it was necessary that this worker *actually does something* and handles the `install` event:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('myapp-store').then((cache) => cache.addAll([
      '/index.html'
    ])),
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  console.log(e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then((response) => response || fetch(e.request)),
  );
});
```

for the `Add to home screen` bottom popup to be displayed in Chrome for Android.

Note: during your tests, if you dismiss the *"Add to home screen"* popup once, you will not see it anymore. A "delete browser history" will be required to see it again. Not very handy to debug this A2HS feature :)

Here is a useful working demo from MDN:

https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/

and in particular the [service worker](https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/sw.js) file.