# How to trigger the simple "Add to home screen" feature (the one without service worker)

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, a2hs

There are in fact two *"Add to home screen"* features on Android browsers:

- The popup dialog that is **automatically** showed on the bottom of Chrome Android **when specific conditions are met** (`manifest.json` available, having a service worker as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742370/ask-the-visitor-of-the-website-to-add-a-home-desktop-shortcut-on-mobile-progres), website visited at least twice in > 5 minutes, etc.)

  [image]
- The Chrome menu item that we can trigger **for any website**, *even* if it does not have a service worker. This one simply creates a shortcut to the website on the home screen of the mobile device:

  [image]

Question: **How to add a button on a HTML page that triggers the creation of a home screen shortcut, like in the second bullet before?** (i.e. for a very simple HTML website, **without** any service worker)

Comment: This library may help https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`BeforeInstallPrompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) event.

```js
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    deferredPrompt = e;
});

const installApp = document.getElementById('installApp');

installApp.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    if (deferredPrompt !== null) {
        deferredPrompt.prompt();
        const { outcome } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;
        if (outcome === 'accepted') {
            deferredPrompt = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a article that might help you.

https://www.amitmerchant.com/adding-custom-install-button-in-progressive-web-apps/

Comment: Is this for my bullet item #1 or #2 of my question?

Comment: Does this work in safari + ios ?

Comment: No, this does not work on safari and firefox. This is a non standard event only available on chromium based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to achieve is not yet possible. In order to be able to make a shortcut, a dedicated API would be needed for that. Until then, there is no API other than service workers that can achieve this.

Comment: This is so wrong in 2022. Just go to countryle.com. It will show popup to add to homescreen

Comment: @lytabu i believe you misunderstood @Basj question. `countryle.com` uses service workers. It prompts the user to install the app rather then creating a simple `Add to home screen` shortcut